# Form to post new post with custom taxonomies

Tags: posts, custom-taxonomy, dropdown

[image]

I have displayed the custom taxonomies in the drop down as you see in the red box  i want to ask that how can i submit them with the post .I can't figure it out.`

```
// Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
if (isset ($_POST['title'])) {
    $title =  $_POST['title'];
} else {
    echo 'Please enter the wine name';
}

// ADD THE FORM INPUT TO $new_post ARRAY
$new_post = array(
'post_title'    =>  $title,
'tax_input' => array(
    'industries' =>  $_REQUEST['taxonomy_id'] ),
'post_status'   =>  'publish',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
'post_type' =>  'websites'  //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
);

//SAVE THE POST
$pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);

//SET OUR TAGS UP PROPERLY

//REDIRECT TO THE NEW POST ON SAVE
$link = get_permalink( $pid );
wp_redirect( $link );

} // END THE IF STATEMENT THAT STARTED THE WHOLE FORM

//POST THE POST YO
do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post');?>`

the form

enter code here
```

Comment: Could you share some more info/code that you are using? Are you using `wp_insert_post();` ?

Comment: yes i am using wp_inser_post();

Comment: this is the form                                                          <div class="catBox">
<a href="#" class="show">Select Industry</a>
<div class="slidingDiv">
<?php $industryterms = get_terms('industries');
foreach ( $industryterms as $industryterm ) {
echo '<div class="clearfix"><input type="checkbox" />'."<label>".$industryterm->name."</label>".'</div>';
 }?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your form to include the term-id, instead of just `<input type="checkbox" />` use `<input type="checkbox" name="taxonomy_id[]" value="'. $industryterm->term_id .'" />`. That way you are actually sending along some values, in this case the term id.

And in the args for `wp_insert_post()` make sure to include something like this:

```
'tax_input' => array(
    'industries' => $_REQUEST['taxonomy_id']
)
```

Comment: and what will be the label

Comment: i am just getting word array in the taxonomy

Comment: Updated the answer, removed the "array( )" part. This should do it.
Not sure what you mean about the label part? You already have a label in the form.

Comment: now i am getting .$industryterm->id. in the taxonomy

Comment: same problem here

Comment: same problem exist

Comment: Can you look in the source code generated on the form page to see if any value are output to the checkbox? Care to share a link?

Comment: i making it in localhost

Comment: i have the problem you were forgeting two commas  value="'. $industryterm->term_id .'"

Comment: Of course! Good spotted! Updated the answer. Is it working now?

Comment: Great, don't forget to mark the question as solved!